# fluent validation collection items not null/empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

Im using fluent validation with mvc4

In my Model I have a list:

```
public List<int> TransDrops { get; set; }
```

in the view im creating text boxes for each item in the list.

I want to subsequently make sure each field is filled in. (not null/empty)

OrderDetailsViewModelValidator is the validator on the model, what do i need?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First you have to use **nullable** integer type for collection item, otherwise empty textboxes would be bound to **zero** value, what makes impossible to distinguish empty textboxes and filled with zeros.

```
public List<int?> TransDrops { get; set; }
```

Next, use predicate validator (**Must** rule):

```
RuleFor(model => model.TransDrops)
    .Must(collection => collection == null || collection.All(item => item.HasValue))
    .WithMessage("Please fill all items");
```

If you need to prevent empty collection being successfully validated, just add `NotEmpty()` rule before predicate validator: it checks that any `IEnumerable` not `null`, and have at least 1 item.

Comment: You should also guard against the list being null, and empty.

Answer (score 12):

There is a simpler approach now, using `RuleForEach`:

```cs
RuleForEach(model => model.TransDrops)
    .NotNull()
    .WithMessage("Please fill all items");
```

Make sure to use `NotNull` and not `NotEmpty`, because NotEmpty validates type's default value (in this case: `int`, it's 0).

You can check for more details in the [documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html?highlight=ruleforeach#collections-of-simple-types)

Comment: Spent several hours working on this, wish I had found this sooner. Much appreciated.